# "Hard-include" in vim script

Tags: vimscript, external-command, include

I want to:

```
let s:asciiart = ["", "", s:hardinclude(system("command params")), "", ""]
```

where `command` returns one string with:

```
"art-line-1", "art-line-2", "art-line-3"
```

so I end up with:

```
s:asciiart == ["", "", "art-line-1", "art-line-2", "art-line-3", "", ""]
```

Is there a way to make a working `s:hardinclude()`? How? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Are you perhaps looking for `systemlist()` ? To be honest, your question is unclear—you've not explained how (algorithmically, not programatically, of course) to get from your input to your output...

Comment: I have contoured this issue by having my "command" return a csv, then splitting the string return value inside vim script environment. So it is solved. I am fairly new to SE, how should this question be marked?

Comment: Welp, if you have a solution, post the answer (self-answering is quite alright!) You might be interested in [help] or [ask]

Comment: @fde-capu The answer using `eval()` is the one you were looking for. But note that's usually a bad idea, generating a Vim snippet from an external command and evaluating it as Vimscript. Instead, generate your output in a more general format (multiple lines, or comma-separated, or tab-separated) and parse that simple format in your Vim code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 8.2.935 introduced a flatten() function (and version 8.2.937 fixed a bug in that function). With this function you can also write

```
let s:asciiart = flatten(["", "", systemlist("command params"), "", ""])
```

to insert the elements of the inner list into the outer list.

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee your original format, you can use

```
split(system(command), ',\s\+')
```

But CSV (as in the self-answer) is probably cleanest.

Alternatively, have the outputs on their own lines and use

```
systemlist(command)
```

Vim unfortunately doesn't have an "explode" operator that I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use `:h eval()`. For example:

```
let s:asciiart = eval('["", "", ' . trim(system("command args")) . ', "", ""]')
```

Note that `system()` output includes extra newline(s), so you have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Although it would still be fine to find out if a "hard-include" would be possible, I answer my own question:

I have changed my `command` to return a CSV, as:

```
art-1,art-2,art3
```

then, from the vim script:

```
let s:asciiart = ["", ""] + split(system("command args"), ",") + ["", ""]
```

...well, solved the problem, but did not exactly answered the question. Not sure if should be marked as solved.

Comment: Better yet, return one item per line and use `systemlist()` to get the result, that already does the split for you as well. Plus, if these are lines of asciiart, then printing it in multiple lines means it will actually *look* like asciiart already, no? 